# Cordova App PushNotification Sound Is Playing When Phone Is Muted

Tags: cordova, push-notification

I've build cordova app, where I use

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push

and

https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp

For sending push notifications.

My problem is that, when push notification comes from my app, sound it played even if phone is muted.
How can I make my app push notifications listen and not ignore to phone volume?

Answer (score 0):

The third is the empty string which will cause for the playing of sound to be skipped.

try add `"soundname": ""`

```
{
  "registration_ids": ["my device id"],
  "data": {
    "title": "Silece",
    "message": "Skips playing any sound",
    "soundname": ""
  }
}
```

Comment: I can't skip playing sound. The only case I don't want sound to play is when phone is muted.